# How much CPU power does it take to process a packet?

Tags: ipv4, cpu

Had a debate with a friend on CPU requirements for networking. I'm not a network engineer, but my understanding is that minimal CPU processing happens for IPv4 network traffic and that it's mostly offloaded to the NIC.

With 1 Gbps internet available in my area the debate was whether you needed a high performing CPU to keep up with the traffic throughput.

I realize the answer may vary greatly depending on OS, NIC, and purpose of the device, but let's assume you have pfSense acting as a simple router/gateway for home use with less than 20 devices (no IDS\IPS\DHCP\DNS\Traffic shaping service), just plain networking (routing\NATing\states). Is there a way to qualify how much CPU processing happens or is required with 100Mbs\1000Mbs\10000Mbs? Is there a way to calculate the typical CPU time required to process a network packet?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is too broad to answer. Dedicated devices may have TCAM that allows a routing table lookup in a single CPU cycle vs. many cycles in a standard PC. Also, NAT is pretty resource intensive if that is used, but a device may have dedicated hardware for NAT. In any case home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry about the off-topic post, I should've read the FAQ before posting, the answer helps clarify, and we can vote to delete post if necessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no standard numbers for that. It greatly depends on the actions performed and the way the software is written. For functions like NAT it also depends on the size of the session table and the rate at which new sessions are created.

To give some anecdotal numbers: I have seen a standard Linux kernel with the Jool NAT64 module handle 8Gbps on a few cores, all the way to VPP handling 190Gbps spread over 32 cores.